# Regex to get specific data from input using the seperator

Tags: regex

I have an below input data with multiple lines and fields seperated by semi colon(;)

```
ABC0131900003.txt|01;2019-01-08;15:06
02;ABC013190102;2019-01-08;;ABC000045;4545.00;0;01;I
03;1;45.01
```

I need to retrieve below specific fields using regex:

- first line: `ABC0131900003.txt`
- second line: `ABC013190102`, `01`, `I`

I'm using regex `\A(?:((?:[^\x7C])*)\x7C)` to get filename, how can i use regex to get second line and 8th and 9th seperated value. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to extract these values: `ABC0131900003.txt`, `ABC013190102`, `01`, `I`?

Comment: Yes, you are rigit!

Comment: What is the regex flavor you are using? Also, you need to tell some logic for extracting your required data, so we can help you create regex accordingly. You need to make it clear that why you don't need `ABC000045` but need `ABC013190102`

Comment: Is it necessary to use regex? In my opinion it would be simpler to split the string into an array (I presume you use it in a script of some kind).

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I'm using Pattern flavour. Logic is second line and 7th seperator(;) to 8th seperator(;) data and 8th to 9th seperator. I need this information ABC013190102, this is keyvalues for the data. need to extract this from the input and pass as parameter to SP

Comment: @montonero Yes, using regex is the proposed logic which will be optimal for our process.

Comment: Try `/^(?:[^;|]*;)?([A-Z][^|;]*)(?:.*;)?([^;]+);([^;]+)$/`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/eWO02T/1).

Comment: Please explain the rules you are trying to follow. Is it some good or invalid CSV? Why use `\A`? Are you using Ruby? You are overusing groups, you may remove redundant ones.